# Manifest merger failed - Don't want to migrate to androidx

Tags: android

I don't want to migrate to androidx. what can I do???

ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-120:19 to override.

Answer (score 0):

Not migrating to `Androidx` will be delimiting to you in the future. If you are sure that your application will not use new APIs or Libraries in the future, then feel free to stick with the `Android` nomenclature. But if you are not certain, then going through the painful process is worth it.

There are documentations that help you to perform this HUGE migration, basically by using incremental approach. Feel free to refer to this document and follow it religiously, by performing small increements.

### Blogs

1. [Androidx official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
2. [Cross stitching android and Androidx](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cross-stitching-plaid-and-androidx-7603a192348e)
3. [Migrating to Androidx Tips](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-androidx-tip-tricks-and-guidance-88d5de238876)

### Video guides

1. [Androidx Video Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hyt7LR5mXLc)